# Running default before_script for all stages

Tags: terraform, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have the following gitlab-ci file:

```yaml
include:
 # To fetch the latest template, use:
  - template: Terraform.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
default:
  before_script:
    - export TF_PATH=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq)
    - export TF_ROOT="$TF_ROOT/$TF_PATH"
variables:
 TF_STATE_NAME: default
 TF_CACHE_KEY: default
 # If your terraform files are in a subdirectory, set TF_ROOT accordingly. For example:
 # TF_ROOT: terraform/production
```

Explanation: I am quite happy with the Gitlab template for `Terraform`, but I have multiple modules inside this repo. In general, my team MRs are always changing only 1 module, then, I just need to get the name/path of that module and change the `TF_ROOT` environment variable to make it work as I need.

And I want this `default:before_script` to run before each `job` on each `stage`. Now it only runs before the `stage:validate`, but `build` and `deploy` are missing that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: do u have a before_script for ur jobs in `build` and `deploy`

Comment: as you can see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml), none of the jobs has the `before_script`, including the jobs from the 1st stage.